# Kotlin: is it possible to have a constant property dependent on an implementation generic type?

Tags: generics, constants, kotlin

I have the following abstrac base class

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number>(open var x: T, open var y: T) {

    companion object {
        val SIZE = 2 * when (/** T instance type */) {
            is Byte, is Ubyte -> 1
            is Short, is Ushort -> 2
            is Int, is Uint, is Float -> 4
            is Long, is Ulong, is Double -> 8
            else -> throw ArithmeticException("Type undefined")
        }
    }
}
```

that is implemented, for example, by `Vec2`

```
data class Vec2(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>(x, y)
```

I am wondering if it is possible to define `SIZE` in `Vec2t` and call on one of its implementation, for example `Vec2.SIZE`

Comment: A `size` property shouldn't be inside the companion object. You don't have access to the `length()`-function there. You can't measure the size of an object before it's created.

Comment: So where shall `size` go for you? I find that it might absolutely be static. Sorry about `length()`, its a wip.

Comment: @elect, seems like it should not be static, because you want size to be different for different instances of Vec2t -- means it should behave differently depending on what it is called on, definitely not the behavior one would expect from something static.

Comment: The JVM does not allow you to have static fields which have different values for different instantiations of a generic class.

Comment: @yole's comment got me thinking more about this and I don't see a use case for a `Vec2t.SIZE`. Even if you could write `Vec2t<Byte>.SIZE` (which you can't) different implementations of `Vec2t<Byte>` could use different sizes (one implementation might use an `Int` to store both bytes instead of two actual `Byte` instances). We want the implementations to provide the size and those can be provided statically (types) and dynamically (instances): http://stackoverflow.com/a/40490174/3255152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you cannot "have static fields which have different values for different instantiations of a generic class" (as [@yole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487257/kotlin-is-it-possible-to-have-a-constant-property-dependent-on-an-implementatio#comment68220690_40487257)), you can define properties on each implementation and their companion objects. e.g.:

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number> {
    abstract var x: T
    abstract var y: T
    abstract val size: Int
}

class Vec2f(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>() {
    companion object {
        const val SIZE = 2 * 4
    }

    override val size: Int
        get() = SIZE
}

class Vec2d(override var x: Double, override var y: Double) : Vec2t<Double>() {
    companion object {
        const val SIZE = 2 * 8
    }

    override val size: Int
        get() = SIZE
}
```

This allows you to reference `Vec2f.SIZE`, `Vec2d.SIZE`, etc. when you want to know the size for a specific implementation and reference `vec2t.size` when you have an instance (possibly of unknown implementation type) and get its size.

Comment: This is exactly how I am ending up doing..!

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect the type of `x` and/or `y` at runtime and lazily initialize a `size` property:

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number>(open var x: T, open var y: T) {
    val size by lazy {
        2 * when (x) {
            is Byte -> 1
            is Short -> 2
            is Int, is Float -> 4
            is Long, is Double -> 8
            else -> throw ArithmeticException("Type undefined")
        }
    }
}
```

If `x` and/or `y` were `final` then you could also skip lazy initialization and initialize it directly:

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number>(var x: T, var y: T) {
    val size = 2 * when (x) {
        is Byte -> 1
        is Short -> 2
        is Int, is Float -> 4
        is Long, is Double -> 8
        else -> throw ArithmeticException("Type undefined")
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted the other one, since it's not possible to achieve it statically. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion, +1

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I like the solution [@mfulton26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255152/mfulton26) suggested, it fits this use case very well. The below answer is rather intended for the cases when you cannot rely on the types of the values (e.g. `T` is `Any`, and you want to know exactly what it is, but all the instances of `T` passed to your class happened to be `String`s).</sup>

---

First, you cannot have a `val` in a  `companion object` that has different values for different instances of your class, because, first of all, the companion object has nothing to do with the instances, it's a separate object and getting its property doesn't (and cannot) involve instances of its enclosing class. Seems like `size` should be a member property.

But even for member properties and functions, inspecting the type argument `T` cannot be done directly, because generics in Kotlin are similar to those in Java and have [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) too, so that at runtime you cannot operate with actual type arguments.

To do that, you can store a `KClass<T>` (or `Class<T>`) object in your `Vec2t<T>` and implement your logic based on it:

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number>(open var x: T, 
                                 open var y: T, 
                                 private val type: KClass<T>) {
    val size: Int by lazy {
        2 * when (type) {
            Byte::class -> 1
            Short::class -> 2
            Int::class, Float::class -> 4
            Long::class, Double::class -> 8
            else -> throw ArithmeticException("Type undefined")
        }
    }
}
```

This would require the subclasses to add the argument to their superclass constructor call:

```
class Vec2(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>(x, y, Float::class)
```

---

If you choose this approach, Kotlin can also offer you [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) for help, so that you can avoid explicitly specifying `SomeType::class` at use site. For example, if your `Vec2t<T>` was not abstract, you could construct it with this factory function:

```
inline fun <reified T: Number> vec2t(x: T, y: T) = Vec2t(x, y, T::class)
```

<sup>With inline functions, you **can** access actual type arguments only because the function is inlined at call sites, thus its type arguments are always known at compile-time. Unfortunately, constructors cannot have any type parameters.</sup>

With usage:

```
val i = vec2t(1, 1) // Vec2t<Int> inferred from arguments type Int
println(i.size) // 8

val d = vec2t(1.0, 1.0) // the same but it's Vec2t<Double> this time
println(d.size) // 16
```

Comment: I might be overlooking something but I believe adding `type` to `Vec2t` can be avoided in lieu of a package-level function: `inline fun <reified T : Number> sizeOfVec2t() = 2 * ...`

Comment: @mfulton26, since `sizeOfVec2t()` is inline, its `reified T` is only determined by the static/inferred type at call site. For example, `(intVec as Vec2t<Number>).sizeOfVec2t()` will fail to discover that `intVec` has `Int` for `T`.

Comment: Ah yes, yes, I thought I might be overlooking something. Thank you @hotkey!